# Mosquitto MQTT on ubuntu for windows

Tags: bash

I'm trying to setup a mosquitto mqtt server on windows using bash on ubuntu on windows because the code I'm try to run is that of Linux but I've been getting this error:

`1588558652: Warning: Mosquitto should not be run as root/administrator.
1588558652: mosquitto version 0.15 (build date 2018-09-05 15:14:14+0000) starting
1588558652: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1588558652: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1588558652: Error: Address already in use`

Then I tried to kill the process by using `ps -ef | grep mosquitto` and I got this `root 26 15 0 2439 ? 00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto` which shows that no process is running. Please what do I do?

Comment: If you surfed for days you should've seen this suggestion, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207649/address-already-in-use-error-in-mosquitto Describe what solutions you've tried and how exactly did they fail? Are sure it's not running already?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did see that "solution" and tried it but this is what I got what I tried to get the process id.           27   15  0  2439   ?   00:00:00

Comment: Describe what you did _exactly_ by **editing the question** and how _exactly_ results of your actions failed to help in solving the problem. `ps -ef` columns order is `UID          PID PPID  C STIME TTY TIME CMD`. The fact that you see a line tells you that it's already running.

Comment: I entered `ps -ef | grep mosquitto` and I got  `root        26    15  0  2439 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto ` then I entered `kill 15` and I got the address already in use error again

Comment: Ok, the only line you have is the process that is searching, so it's not running. I'll continue trying to help only after you've edited your question with this info and with info on what you were doing previously that resulted in the output you've provided.

Comment: I've done that. Thanks

Comment: Well, not really. You didn't include what you were doing previously. Why are you running it as root if it warns you not to? What guide did you follow? I feel like I've spent more time trying to help you than you trying to make it work and researching the question.